# would rather had been doing something

Tags: construction

I want to know how to use "the past perfect continuous" with "would rather".

Do these make sense?

I would rather you had been revising for the last ten minutes.
I would rather you had been visiting them for the last week.
I would rather you had been going swimming for the last week of our holiday at the seaside.

Answer (score 1):

Well yes, it's probably grammatical, but my brain gave up trying to understand the sentence about half way into the verb phrase - and that is a good sign that something is wrong.

English tends to be analytical, which means that that you can create a long verb phrase from many words, using auxiliaries, modals and so on (rather than by synthetically modifying the form of the verb itself) This doesn't mean that such a phrase is clear or is likely to be understood.

So, no, don't do that. Say:

> You should've been revising for the last ten minutes.

> Why didn't you visit them last week?

> I wish you'd gone swimming during the last week of our holiday at the seaside.

These don't mean exactly the same, but they have the great advantage of being understandable.